# How to get copy, paste, and cut in Samsung's Android SDK S-Pen Composer

Tags: android, samsung-mobile-sdk

So I'm making an app that uses Samsung's Pen SDK, the only problem is in their example, ComposerSample7_1_Composer, there is code for creating the context menus,

```
private void createContextMenu(Menu menu) {
    final boolean editable = mSpenComposerView.getMode() == SpenComposerView.MODE_EDIT;
    final SpenSDoc.CursorInfo begin = mSDoc.getSelectedRegionBegin();
    final SpenSDoc.CursorInfo end = mSDoc.getSelectedRegionEnd();

    Log.d(TAG, "SpenContextMenuListener$createContextMenu : " + begin.index + " - " + end.index);

    menu.add(Menu.NONE, CONTEXT_MENU_ID_CUT, CONTEXT_MENU_ID_CUT, "CUT")
            .setEnabled(editable);
    menu.add(Menu.NONE, CONTEXT_MENU_ID_COPY, CONTEXT_MENU_ID_COPY, "COPY")
            .setEnabled(mSDoc.isSelected());
    menu.add(Menu.NONE, CONTEXT_MENU_ID_PASTE, CONTEXT_MENU_ID_PASTE, "PASTE")
            .setEnabled(editable);
    menu.add(Menu.NONE, CONTEXT_MENU_ID_SELECT_ALL, CONTEXT_MENU_ID_SELECT_ALL, "SELECT ALL")
            .setEnabled(true);

    if (begin.index >= 0 && begin.index == end.index) {
        switch (mSDoc.getContent(begin.index).getType()) {
            case SpenContentBase.TYPE_HANDWRITING:
                break;
            case SpenContentBase.TYPE_DRAWING:
                menu.add(Menu.NONE, CONTEXT_MENU_ID_RESIZE_IMAGE, CONTEXT_MENU_ID_RESIZE_IMAGE, "RESIZE")
                        .setEnabled(editable);
                break;
            case SpenContentBase.TYPE_IMAGE:
                menu.add(Menu.NONE, CONTEXT_MENU_ID_RESIZE_IMAGE, CONTEXT_MENU_ID_RESIZE_IMAGE, "RESIZE")
                        .setEnabled(editable);
                break;
            case SpenContentBase.TYPE_VOICE:
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

But the there is no actions for what to do when these items are selected, this is what the sample code has:

```
private boolean executeMenuItem(MenuItem item) {
    final SpenSDoc.CursorInfo begin = mSDoc.getSelectedRegionBegin();
    final SpenSDoc.CursorInfo end = mSDoc.getSelectedRegionEnd();

    Log.d(TAG, "SpenContextMenuListener$executeMenuItem : " + item.getItemId() + " / " + begin.index + " - " + end.index);

    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case CONTEXT_MENU_ID_CUT:
            //TODO
            break;
        case CONTEXT_MENU_ID_COPY:
            //TODO

            break;
        case CONTEXT_MENU_ID_PASTE:
            //TODO

            break;
        case CONTEXT_MENU_ID_RESIZE_IMAGE: {
            if (!mSDoc.isSelected()) {
                return true;
            }
            final SpenContentBase contentImage = mSDoc.getContent(begin.index);
            if (contentImage != null
                    && (contentImage.getType() == SpenContentBase.TYPE_IMAGE || contentImage.getType() == SpenContentBase.TYPE_DRAWING)) {
                mSpenComposerView.setResizeHandleVisible(true);
                mSDoc.setCursorPosition(begin.pos > 0 ? begin : end);
                mSoftInput.hide((Activity) mContext);
            }
        }
        break;
        case CONTEXT_MENU_ID_SELECT_ALL:
            selectAll();
            break;
    }

    return true;
}
```

How can I get these actions to work?
[This](https://developer.samsung.com/galaxy/pen) is where Samsung's SDK is located, including all the sample code. Thanks for any help, this is my first post, so sorry if I messed something up!

Answer (score 0):

@WalkingHat Samsung S-Pen SDK wrapper library don't support these kind of features

A Samsung S-Pen library for Android that handles most of the common use cases with a single class only with much reduced complexity compared with Samsung SDK Pen package.

> which support:  Pen of various styles, colors and adjustable size
>
> Eraser of adjustable size
>
> Undo, redo
>
> Zoom
>
> Scroll automatically when the pen is hovering near an edge of the
>   canvas
>
> Replay of strokes with different speed
>
> Instance thumbnail generation
>
> Multi-page support
>
> Re-order pages
>
> Color background
>
> Image background
>
> Supported events: onTouch, onReplayCompleted, onPageUpdated, onCommit,
>   undo, redo
>
> Draw using S-Pen or finger

you need to your code for these

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you mean. If this isn't possible using the Pen SDK, how is Samsung doing it in their Samsung Notes app?